# Custom error message for various HTML5 validation attributes

Tags: html

Is there a way to provide custom messages(error messages) when a validation fails on an input control?

Eg:

```
<input type="number" value="" min="1" max="5">
```

Enter value 10 and then submit the form it shows 
"Please select a value which is no more than 5"

This can be done using javascript, but I am much interested in HTML5 way without third party library.

I am unable to find the attributes related to error message in HTML5 documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check if they match a certain pattern and if so then make the submit button visible.

For more information see: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/

**Example:**

```css
input:required:invalid,
input:focus:invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
input:required:valid {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
input[type="submit"] {
  display: none;
}
input:required:valid ~ input[type="submit"] {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<b>Website:</b>
<input type="url" name="website" required pattern="https?://.+">
<input type="submit"><br/>
<i>Submit is only visible when you fill in a website starting with: http(s)://</i>
```

Comment: Ok, that means no direct way to inject using html attributes...:(